# Wonderware - Intouch: demo license

Tags: wonderware

I am working with a computer that has a windows viewer license but I have to do a couple of design things with windows maker. Is there a way to get in with a demo license to do them? In ifix for example you can enter as a demo for 2 hours. Is there something like it for wonder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the demo mode as long as the application has less than 32 tags defined. Otherwise you need yo contact your local distributor since they are who can decide if providing or not a demo license to you
If you have an active customer first contract, you will probably get the license. Otherwise it is up to your local distributor.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no 2 hours demo licenses. A demo license is for 1 calendar month, i.e. expires at the end of the month when it was obtained.

Wonderware is now owned by Aveva and the licensing model has been changing over last couple years, but the last time I checked (1 year ago) it was still possible to obtain a 1 month demo license as a file, and activate it using Aveva License Manager (formerly Schneider Electric License Manager) installed locally.

I think to get a demo license you'll need to register with Aveva support center https://softwaresupportsp.aveva.com/ I'm not sure though about legality of using a demo license for making changes to an application used commercially... you'd need to read their T&Cs.